# Norm of Bilinear Map Definition Confusion

Tags: functional-analysis

I must be missing something simple...

For a bilinear map $B: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$, the norm of the map is defined as
$$\|B\| :=\sup_{\|x\| \leq 1, \hspace{1mm} \|y\| \leq 1} \|B(x, y)\|_Z.$$
This definition implies the following inequality:
$$\|B(x, y)\|_Z \leq \|B\| \cdot\|x\|_X \cdot \|y\|_Y.$$
This definition is not what I would have guessed.  I would have guessed the following definition:
$$\|B\| :=\sup_{\|x\| = 1, \hspace{1mm} \|y\| = 1} \|B(x, y)\|_Z$$
which I thought would imply the same inequality:
$$\|B(x, y)\|_Z \leq \|B\| \cdot\|x\|_X \cdot \|y\|_Y.$$
Can someone tell me why my definition of choice would fail to imply the inequality of interest that inspired the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are actually equivalent.

Clearly $$\sup_{\|x\| = \|y\| = 1} \left\| B(x,y)\right\| \le \sup_{\|x\|, \|y\| \le 1} \left\| B(x,y)\right\|$$

Conversely, let $x,y \in X$ such that $\|x\|, \|y\| \le 1$.

We have:

$$\left\|B(x,y)\right\| = \underbrace{\|x\|\|y\|}_{\le 1}\left\|B\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|},\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)\right\| \le \left\|B\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|},\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)\right\| \le \sup_{\|u\| = \|v\| = 1} \left\| B(u,v)\right\|$$

Taking the supremum over all $x,y \in X$ such that $\|x\|, \|y\| \le  1$ we obtain

$$\sup_{\|x\|, \|y\| \le 1} \left\| B(x,y)\right\| \le \sup_{\|x\| = \|y\|= 1} \left\| B(x,y)\right\|$$

Comment: This looks solid.  I had a similar justification.  I was worried that I was missing some technical point, but it appears that the definitions are equivalent.  I am curious why the definition with the inequalities is more common, as for linear maps of a single variable the definition of the norm is typically given as the supremum over the unit sphere.

Comment: @BenB For a linear map $A$ the four of these are quite common:

$$\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1}\|Ax\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \inf\{M > 0 : \|Ax\| \le M\|x\|, \forall x \in X\}$$

Also if $X$ is an inner product space then

$$\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\|, \|y\| \le 1}\left|\langle Ax, y\rangle\right| = \sup_{\|x\|= \|y\| = 1}\left|\langle Ax, y\rangle\right|$$
which is very similar to the definition of norm $\|B\|$.